# Can MuleSoft API/Anypoint copy data from one database's table to another database's table without any additional step (any custom code)?

Tags: api, dataweave, mulesoft

**Goal:**
I have two SQL server databases (DB-A and DB-B) located on two different severs in same network.
DB-A has a table T1 and I want to copy data from DB-A's Table T1 (source) to DB-B's Table T2 (Destination). This DB sync should take palace anytime any record in T1 is added, updated, and deleted.

**Please note:** All db to db data syc options are out of consideration, I must use **MuleSoft API** for this job.

**Background:**
I am new to MuleSoft and its offered products, I am told mule soft platform can help with building and managing API’s.
I explored web for MuleSoft offering, there are many articles (mentioned below) which are suggesting that MuleSoft itself can read and write from one DB table and write to another DB table (using DB connectors etc).

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible that MuleSoft itself can get this data sync job done without us writing own MuleSoft API invoker or MuleSoft API Consumer (to trigger MuleSoft API from one end or to receive data from MuleSoft API on the other end and write to DB table)?
2. What are all key steps to get this data transfer working? If you can provide any reference which shows step by step journey to achieve the goal will be huge help.

**Links:**

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXXGDSA4/copy-data-from-one-oracle-table-to-another-oracle-table

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXStnSAG/select-insert-data-from-one-database-to-another

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D72T000003rpJJSAY/detail

Comment: When you said MuleSoft (the company name) do you really mean Mule runtime ( one of MuleSoft's products)? Otherwise it seems that you are expecting the company to work on your project.

Comment: aled, thanks for your input, further explained issue clearly points to mulesoft apis. Like I said I am new to Mulesoft, I am unsure if there are other products from MuleSoft which can help me to achieve as mentioned. Do you know any?

Comment: Mule runtime or Composer seem appropriate. Your question however must specific or it could be closed as opinion based or lack of focus. When you say I'm new to MuleSoft it seems to imply you are a new MuleSoft employee, which is not probably what you intend to say.

Comment: I believe MuleSoft employees must be having better internal resources than just posting question Stack Overflow.  By saying "New to MuleSoft" my intent is I am to MuleSoft and any of its offering.

Comment: In some cases employees ask questions here so the answers are also available to the community.

Answer (score 1):

First let's clarify the terminology since the questions mixes several concepts in a confusing way. MuleSoft is a company that has several products that may apply. A MuleSoft API should be considered an API created by MuleSoft. Since you clearly are talking about APIs created by you or your organization that would be an incorrect description. What you are talking about are really Mule applications, which are applications that are deployed and executed in a Mule runtime. Mule applications may implement your APIs, or may implement integrations. After all Mule originally was an ESB product used to integrate other systems, before REST APIs where a thing. You may deploy Mule applications to Anypoint Platform. Specifically to the CloudHub component of the platform, or to an on-prem instance of Mule runtime.

In any case, a Mule application is perfectly capable of implementing APIs, integrations or both. There is no need that it implements an API or call another API if that is not what you want. You need to trigger the flow somehow, either reading directly from the database to find new rows, with a scheduler to execute a query at a given time, an HTTP request or even have an API listening for requests to trigger the flow.

As an example the application can use the <db:listener> source of the Database connector to start the flow fetching rows. You need to take care of any watermark columns configurations to detect only new rows. See the documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-documentation#listener for details.

Alternatively you can trigger the flow in another way and just use a [select operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-documentation#select).

After that use DataWeave to transform the records as needed. Then use [insert](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-documentation#insert) or [update](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-documentation#update) operations.

There are examples in the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-connector-examples) that can help you to get started. If you are not familiar with Mule you should start with reading the documentation and do some training until you get the concepts.

Comment: @user11251420 if you want that level of detail in your answer you need to be more specific with your question. Specify what you have tried, and what is not working for you. You can not expect a full mule working mule app without putting any effort yourself. Database synchronisation can be complicated and may depend on your specific requirements. What kind on columns do you have? How often the sync needs to take place? Is there an auto incremental column? etc etc. You question is very high level and it really seems that you have no idea and are looking for a pointers just like aled has given.

Comment: "Specify what you have tried" - I have not tried anything yet, goal here is to find out is it even possible what has been asked?

Comment: "You can not expect a full mule working mule app without putting any effort yourself" - I have been told that MuleSoft will provide APIs to achieve the goal, but application team (applications using DB-A and DB-B as mentioned in question) need to write a layer to invoke MuleSoft API on one end and on other team need to write MuleSoft API consumer/listener to write data to database. - This Goal can be achieved by simple REST Api, WCF etc etc.... Why MuleSoft in that case?

Comment: "Database synchronisation can be complicated" - Indeed, consider simplest possible scenario One table with two varchar fields pushing data into other table with two varchar fields.

Comment: "I have not tried anything yet, goal here is to find out is it even possible what has been asked?" That question has been responded in my answer. Yes, it can be done with Mule runtime. I also gave you pointers to the components that you need to use and some tips. I'm not quite sure what is your expectation of an answer. Please clarify in your question or accept the answer.

Comment: "How often the sync needs to take place" - As I am told MuleSoft has some offering to make it Realtime, and it's one of key feature why I am exploring MuleSoft solution

Comment: "I have been told that MuleSoft will provide APIs to achieve the goal, but application team ..." I'm not sure what that means but seems more like an organizational problem than a technical issue that can be discussed here. I recommend to discuss that with the person that told you that.

Comment: I guess, I need to consult (one to one on phone) with some MuleSoft consultant who has experience in this area. Stack Overflow is not a suitable place to get answers for potentially complex/ confusing cases like this.  Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I agree with you. For future reference you can read the Help Center section on how to ask questions that provides guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking